# Deprecated API warning

Tags: flutter, plugins, geocoding

I updated my plugins to latest versions but got this message when build singed APK using Android studio.

### Warning:

```
geocoding-2.0.2/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geocoding/GeocodingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details
```

Please help me to solve this warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a warning showing that the `geocoding package` uses deprecated API.

This will not cause any problem.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it ?